# How to send email from C

Tags: c, email, authentication, smtp, starttls

How can I send an email using C?

I was searching around for a few days then finally decided to ask.

I tried this http://www.muquit.com/muquit/software/mailsend/mailsend.html but couldn't get it working as it didn't recognize the -starttls command. I'll mention my main target is gmail servers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dup, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210/c-smtp-example

Comment: thats a C++ example @L7ColWinters

Comment: Actually, the C++ program listed there uses the good old C sockets API.

Answer (score 0):

You mention in a comment that you could launch a separate program from C.  So launch [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/) or     mail or something similar, and be done with it.  So long as you pay attention to error handling and don't send so many emails that it becomes a performance problem, it should work OK.